# Xcode on Real Device Developer Mode disable

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

on Real Device that has iOS versions 16 this issue its shown. it was working fine on iOS below then version 16. any solution for this;

Answer (score -1):

On the latest iOS version 16.0 for security purpose new feature is introduced the is Developer Mode.

To enable Developer Mode go to Settings/Privacy & Security on the iOS device. Scroll down to the Developer Mode list item and navigate into it.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device) is the complete Article  For.